# Strange error using JPA on OpenShift

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, openshift

I got an error I am worrying about for days already - also because it is hard to test whether it still occurs or not.

From an Java EE application hosted at OpenShift I am connecting to a MySQL cartridge. I am using JPA (Hibernate) to handle my connection and for ORM purposes.

The connection and the application itself is working fine - but when trying to access the database after some hours (I guess after OpenShift "hibernated" the servlet) it doesn't work anymore.

I get the following exception (that is just an excerpt, but it seems to me to be the most important part):

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870)
```

Of course I know what the exception is trying to the me - I just do not know why it is thrown...

My database access class looks the following:

```
public class JPAUtils implements ServletContextListener {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JPAUtils.class);
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private static EntityManager em;

    public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactoryInstance() {
        if (emf == null || !emf.isOpen()) {
            String environment = "test";

            if (System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL") != null) {
                environment = "production";
            }

            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(environment);
        }

         return emf;
    }

    public static EntityManager getEntityManagerInstance() {
        if (em == null || !em.isOpen()) {
            em = getEntityManagerFactoryInstance().createEntityManager();
        }

        return em;
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        log.debug("Context initialized!");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        try {
            log.debug("Closing JPA connection...");
            em.close();
            emf.close();
            em = null;
            emf = null;

            log.debug("Closed JPA connection!");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error occurred during closing of JPA connection!", e);
        }
    }
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="test">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/<db_name>?autoReconnect=true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="***" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="***" />


            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="10" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="production">
        <!-- If you are running in a production environment, add a managed
           data source, this example data source is just for development and testing! -->
        <!-- The datasource is deployed as WEB-INF/kitchensink-quickstart-ds.xml, you
           can find it in the source at src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/kitchensink-quickstart-ds.xml -->
        <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/MySQLDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <!--<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I already looked up many examples and tutorials - but I cannot find the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping around references to `EntityManager` instances is never a good practice, the static variable `em` in your case is keeping a stall object after the connection is closed.

Best practices advice to scope `EntityManager`s to the current transaction.

Comment: Ok, good point.
But that probably won't fix it, at least if I got your advice right....

Comment: Yes, I think it should, if the connection is closed for any reason (passivation, etc.) the EntityManager you keep in the static variable continues to use it, and it is closed. That's the origin of the error I think.

Comment: Ok, so after exhausting testing it seems to work this way - thank you!
So it seems (this is also what the error message said) that entityManager has been closed - I just expected em.isOpen() to return false in case the connections gets closed... Ok, that might be because of setting em = null and there might be a limit for active entityManger instances....